# How action potential is generated while dreaming

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, dreams, brain

I would like to know what generates the action potential in the brain areas that is relevant to dreaming, since our sensory nervous systems don't work (or do they?). What else can generate the action potential needed for dreaming?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to unpack here, but maybe a good place to start is looking at the difference between an action potential and a brainwave. An [action potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_potential) is the abrupt change in voltage of a single neuron in response to a pre-synaptic stimulus. Brainwaves are measured by [EEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography). They represent the sum of many neurons' activity.

If I understand the gist of your question, you want to know where the brain activity "comes from" during sleep/dreaming since there are no sensory stimuli. It's a good question, and a topic of research. Check out [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867419307433) or any of Gyorgy Buzsaki's work. Also, you may be interested in the [Default mode network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_mode_network).